# Rails link_to syntax in order to add some inner html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I have this code to generate a "unfollow" button via the 'link_to' function:

```
<%= link_to "Non seguire più", user_user_relationship_path(id:@relationship.id), remote: true, id: "follow_#{@user.id}", class:"btn btn-small btn-danger", method: :delete %>
```

I would like to know ho to use the "do..end" syntax with all those arguments.. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would you want to stick a block in there?

Comment: i would like to add an icon, as illustrated in bootstrap [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just skip the first parameter, can wrap the rest in parens, and then add the do/end.

```
<%= link_to(user_user_relationship_path(id:@relationship.id), remote: true, id: "follow_#{@user.id}", class:"btn btn-small btn-danger", method: :delete) do %>
  <!-- your button html here -->
<% end %>
```